# PHP Security Addon

Tags: php, security, mobile, two-factor-authentication

I want to use a mobile code system such that when logging into a website (using a computer), the user will get a text message asking them to enter a code before they can login.

In doing this, what are the chances of the user's information being compromised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question and it's impossible to tell what level of attacker sophistication you are talking about. If you want to know how hack-safe mobile phones are, that would be off-topic here. Maybe that would work on [IT security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/), I don't know.

But generally, to state the obvious: If the hacker doesn't have access to the mobile phone, it becomes very difficult to break in - at least as far as the route of stealing or guessing the user's credentials is concerned.

Google are employing something similar as an [optional additional security feature.](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056284): If you log in from a client that Google hasn't seen yet, you are sent an activation code to your mobile phone.

Comment: i am extremley sorry.  i meant to say website using a computer.  i have updated my question.

Comment: is there a way a hacker can use a login page and break in without guessing anybody's credentials and get access to all data? And what if they sign up for an account and then manipulate the password? etc.  So i think having this would prevent a major hack...?

Comment: @AAA sure, if your system is badly programmed, any of these things may be possible. If it's well programmed, then no. It's hard to give any more specific advice - what you ask is pretty much what IT security is all about

Comment: is it possible i can email you some scripts i have been working on? i am new and have been working on this for a year so want to make sure i don't go crazy! thanks let me know!

Comment: @AAA sorry, I have a deskful of work in front of me already :) There are many resources on general PHP security on the web, and one [book by Chris Shiflett](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-PHP-Security-Chris-Shiflett/dp/059600656X) that is said to be pretty good. Then there's SO questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices) that might help.